# Suggestions regarding prework out supplements to boost workout

Tags: workout, supplements, pre-workout

I am thinking to take a prework out supplements which can help me keep energised during workout and help me do hardcore workout.

Right now i am doing weight lifting exercise like Chest,back,Bicep,shoulder etc.I have decided like after i finish my weight lifting exercise(like i did my chest exercise today) i will do cardio for 15-20 along with stretching but problems is i am unable to do it.Sometimes i do only running for 10 minutes after that i am not able to do anything and i dont know why i get so de-energised so early so that i am not able to do cardio.

Right now i am taking following things half an hooru before before hitting the gym :

```
1 glass of juice.
1 glass of milk which contains some dry fruits along with banana.
```

One of my friend is taking [BCAA](https://in.bodybuilding.com/store/sv/xtend.html) and i can see that he is able to do heavy liftings than me and he told me that BCAA helped him alot and gives him boost.

One of my friend also suggested me [Cobra Lab curse](https://in.bodybuilding.com/store/cobra-labs/the-curse.html).So guys can you suggest me any good prework supplements which can help me do hardcore workout and doesnt have any kind of side effects?

Comment: This appears to be a shopping question, can you rephrase it to be more inline with the stack question-answer style?

Comment: @JJosaur I wanted some good suggestions on some good preworkout things to be taken before hitting the gym

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you should look to get your “energy” from quality food, rather than supplements.  The supplement industry is a [billion dollar industry](http://www.nutraingredients-usa.com/Markets/NBJ-The-US-supplement-industry-is-37-billion-not-12-billion) laden with promises for quick gains.  While some supplements may benefit the user, it’s best to not rely solely on a “magic pill” to enhance performance.  Rather, make sure you are getting sufficient rest and consuming quality protein, carbohydrate and fat.

Comment: Can you sugest some good things to be taken before hitting the gym.Do you think i am taking enough before hitting the gym?

Comment: In my opinion, you are low on calories if you want to work out hard.  And, since calorie/food consumption is a very individual thing, you need to learn what works for you.

Comment: What are you taking as preworkout?

Comment: I try not to plan meals around working out.  I'd rather make sure that I consume a steady flow of nutrients **throughout** the day by consuming several small meals.  This insures there are no "highs" and "lows" in energy during the day.

Comment: But workout on empty stomach is not good at all if you might have research on this

Comment: Meal timing for the optimal "protein synthesis" and the "anabolic window" is all broscience, just eat right, eat enough and in moderation. If you really need energy before a workout then just have a black coffee.

Comment: @JJosaur Can i drink juice,milk with banana along with black coffee?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't compare yourself to others. This is especially important when concerning fitness and nutrition. Your body may be *similar* but it is not the **same** as other people. Also be careful about drawing your own assumptions on causality: Your friend's intake of BCAAs is unlikely to be the reason he is lifting more than you.

## On BCAA's

The meta-analysis completed by [examine.com](https://examine.com/supplements/branched-chain-amino-acids/) summerises:

> Branched Chain Amino Acids (BCAAs) are three amino acids with similar structures that beneficially influence the muscles. They can be found in any food containing protein, such as eggs or meat. Supplementation is not necessary, but BCAAs may benefit the body if taken at specific times.

Summarising the meta-analysis from examine (I recommend you go read it), supplementing BCAA's may improve your recovery during a fasted state where you might not be able to obtain them form your diminished diet. The effect on reducing perceived fatigue is more noticeable in untrained/beginner individuals. Remember that utilising the placebo-effect can be a very real performance enhancer for untrained individuals. You observing this and commenting to him only serves to increase his perception of the (potential) placebo intra-exercise 'energy boost'.

## On Preworkout

Pre-workout is a multi-billion-dollar industry, and everyone is looking for that little pill to make you "get ripped in 30 days!"(tm). In reality, most preworkouts follow the same formula with some extra "special enchancers" that have no scientifically backed evidence to prove they enhance your performance.

We know that the following do improve performance:

- [Creatine](https://examine.com/supplements/creatine/): Though you can get this from eating enough meat and the timing of taking creatine does not matter.
- [BCAAs](https://examine.com/supplements/branched-chain-amino-acids/): As above, can help improve recovery. You can get this from food.
- [Caffeine](https://examine.com/supplements/caffeine/): Raises your heart rate and give the feeling of higher energy levels. The "healthiest" way to get it is either pure (pill form) or from black coffee.
- The rest is just stuff that might give you a stronger pump, might help you recover, might help you burn fat for longer or might increase your chance of a early-age heart attack, a lot of pre-workout is unregulated by the FDA.

To assess the suitability of a pre-workout, check it on labdoor.com which is a un-biased website comparing the scientific composition of these powders (amongst other things). Don't just look at the numbers, read into their investigations. Here is the page for your chosen pre-workout: https://labdoor.com/review/cobra-labs-the-curse-pre-workout/report

#### *Personal Recommendation:*

- Don't compare yourself to others.
- Put the hard work in, develop mental toughness.
- Take creatine, 5 grams, every day, forever.
- Drink water.
- If you are low on energy you can occasionally use coffee as pre-workout.
- Rest enough.
- Eat enough and eat well.

Comment: This is really beautifull and yes today i have tried your suggestion like i have drink 1 cup of black tea half an hour before hitting the gym though it was good but later on i feel bit uncomfortable after workout and i drink cocunut water.What creatine you are taking and can you please send me link for that please